# How do I separate the files and directories so that I can perform some action/process on files?

Tags: shell, hadoop, awk, hdfs

From a given directory I'm listing out all the files and directories by using following command.

```
`hadoop dfs -lsr <path to hdfs directory>`
```

This list files and directories

```
drwxrwxrwx   - root xyz          0 2014-10-09 18:39 <path to directory>
-rw-rw-rw-   3 root xyz  133998512 2015-04-08 03:36 <path to file>
```

I would like to have a script which takes these outputs and filter the file path only. I believe just looking at the first char of each line will be sufficient 
drwxrwxrwx and -rw-rw-rw- but I don't know how do I write a script for it. Probably I need to learn awk.

Comment: What do you want to do with this information? If you want to give it for some processing by hadoop, you can obtain it when you are setting up your hadoop job.

Comment: I will be using this to my c++ code. These files are encoded, I have to pass the entire file in decode function and then search for a query string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use AWK for this.

```
 hadoop dfs -lsr <path to hdfs directory> | awk '{ if($1 !~ /d.*/) { print $0; } }'
```

**Explanation:**
   AWK divides the input stream into columns. The columns are numbered 1 to $NF, the number of fields.

$1 denotes the first column -- the drwxrwxrwx thingy. This code tests whether the first column starts with a 'd'. If it does not start with a 'd', it proceeds into the block and prints the whole row. (The $0 is used to denote the whole row, while $1, $2, etc. denote the columns in the row).

**EDIT**: If you want to print the filenames only, replace "print $0;" with "print $NF;"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the processing in a distributed fashion, you might want to see [hadoop streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/HadoopStreaming.html).

If you really want to only find the files and the version of your hadoop is >= 2.7 (at the moment it is not released yet), you can use `find`. According to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8989) issue, the feature has been added in version `2.7.0`.

Another option is to use the solution with `awk` that was already provided or with `grep`

```
hadoop dfs -lsr <path to hdfs directory> | grep -v '^d'
```

Or to obtain only the name of the file:

```
hadoop dfs -lsr <path to hdfs directory> | grep -v '^d' | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 8 -d ' '
```

Here we take only the lines that start with a `d` and then we compress the spaces into a single space and we take a specific column of the result.

Comment: '^d' will ignore all the file name starting with 'd'  won't it ?

Comment: You are right that there is a mistake, but it is that currently it will take only the directories. For the files you need to add `-v`. I will edit the post to fix this. The reason it works is that the first word in every row is about the permissions (not exactly, but anyway). The first letter in every row is `d` if the entity is a directory (`^` means the begining of the line). This is why you can use `grep` or `awk`. If you look  closely the awk answer uses exactly the same thing.